# How merge values inside column into single row seperated by commas in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge

I have integer column in dataframe.

```
dt.Values.dtypes

dtype('int64')
```

Input

```
Df.Values
1234
34567
2344
1234
1222
```

Expected output

```
('1234','34567','2344','1234','1222')
```

How can this be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert values to strings and then to tuple:

```
out = tuple(dt.Values.astype(str))
```

Or:

```
out = tuple(map(str, dt.Values))
#alternative
#out = tuple([str(x) for x in dt.Values])

print (out)
('1234', '34567', '2344', '1234', '1222')
```

If want string separated by `,`:

```
out1 = ', '.join(dt.Values.astype(str))
print (out1)
1234, 34567, 2344, 1234, 1222
```